# How do I restrict the number of characters returned from a query using Sequel and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

My model is `Article`, and I want to display just a snippet of the body of the article, to give a preview of this particular article.

How would I do that with Sequel?

I thought it might be using `limit`, but that just limits the number of records returned from the db.

Ideally I would like to do something like: `Article.first.limit(40)` where 40 is the first 40 characters.

I know `limit` won't work, but I am just using it as an example to illustrate what I am looking for.

---

Edit 1:

I am using Sinatra. I wanted to restrict the returned values but from the view, rather than the routing file.

I do something like this in the routing file:

```
@section = HelpSections.filter(:type => 'a').order(:sort, :name)
```

Which gives me a list of all sections of type `a`.

Then, to get to an article I do:

```
@section.each do |article|
     article.question.each do |title|
         title.name[0..9]
     end
end
```

Based on this scenario, what I want to do is restrict the size of the 'name' attribute returned.

But, when I do that, I get this error:

```
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I handle this, so that I can restrict the size of the `name` attribute?

Comment: The problem is that title.name is returning nil (nothing). Did are you sure you didn't mean something like this:

    `@section.each do |article|`
      `article.name[0..9]`

Comment: Sorry, I added `article.question.each do |title|`...it shouldn't return `nil`, if it is parsing the characters in the article. If I do `article.name` it returns the full value (which is long). When I do `article.name[0..9]`, that's when it complains which leads me to believe that it may be looking for a record in name, and not parsing the characters...if that makes sense.

Comment: Try `article.name.to_s[0..9]`

Comment: You can update your answer, if you want, to more accurately reflect the updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not just do something like this?:

```
Article.first[:body][0..39]
```

If you really need to do it through SQL, you can do something like this:

```
Article.select {|a| a.substr(:body, 1, 40) }
```

(You may have to use `.substring` in place of `substr` depending on your DB)

Comment: Hey Alex...one more question...I am going to update the question for how I can handle this in the view.

Comment: Are you using Rails? If so, take a look at `truncate`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate